# Angular cart's list in numbers instead of multiple rows

Tags: angular, typescript, cart

I'm developing an ecommerce using Angular 9 but i'm stuck on something i've never did. In the cart component i would like to see how many units of the same product is in there in a single row once added, for example [product RTX 3060 x 2] instead of seeing the same product in multiple rows, example:
[product: RTX 3060]
[product: RTX 3060]

cart.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from '../../../services/cart.service';
import { ProductDTO } from '../../../models/generics/product.model';
import { ProductService } from '../../../services/product.service';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css'],
})


export class CartComponent implements OnChanges{

  products = this.cartService.getProducts();

  
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartService.getCartDetailsByUser();
    this.updateProducts();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['cartService']) {
      this.updateProducts();
    }
  }

  updateProducts() {
    return localStorage.getItem('products');
  }



  get totalPrice() {
    return this.products.reduce((acc, product) => acc + product.PriceWithIVA, 0).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```